# C# SqlDataAdapter SelectCommand: pass in parameter into TSQL 'execute'

Tags: c#, t-sql, sqldataadapter

From withing C#, I want to run an SQL command (business intelligence) based on the SQL Server version.
So the command is something like

```
if newVersion
    SELECT some cool stuff
else
    SELECT some old stuff
```

Since the new version contains functionality that is not available in old SQL Server versions, the only way I found to do this was via the execute function in TSQL

```
if newVersion
    execute('new SELECT')
else
    execute ('old SELECT')
```

So far so good.

I also want to pass in a parameter - actually a DateTime that will be part of the WHERE clause of the SELECT.

To make things even more interesting, I will pass the DateTime @StartDate from C# code via an SqlDataAdapter that passes a .net string statement as the TSQL text into the SelectCommand and calls Fill. Something like

```
adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(statement, con);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(myStartDate);
adapter.Fill(ds, resultTableName);
```

But.. for the life of me, I couldn't get it into the SQL to work. I always get some syntax error exception when calling the Fill method (executing the code).

Both passing in parameters (to no dynamic SQL) as well as hard coding a parameter into the dynamic SQL works. But not the combination.

My SQL (just for testing) looks something like

```
EXECUTE('SELECT ''' + @MyStartDate + '''
')
```

Where I try to convert the parameter into part of the SQL command text that is to be executed on the server.

I get

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near SELECT
```

I want to use the parameter added from C# in the SQL query that is executed via the execute command.

Comment: Don't use `EXEC ({SQL Statement})` you can't parametrise the statement. Use a **parametrised** call to [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comment, don't use `EXEC ({SQL Statement/Variable})` when using dynamic SQL, instead use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which can be parametrised.

We don't have any real example code here, so I'm going to use your overly simplified statement, which would be:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate date = GETDATE();

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT @StartDate;';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@StartDate date', @StartDate = @StartDate;
```

Comment: I could have continued failing all day.. many thanks, it works (with the demo, still have to edit the "real" code).